# How to navigate through bookmarked directories in helm-find-files?

Tags: helm, helm-sources

I have some bookmarked directories (regular Emacs bookmarks). I'd like helm-find-files to quickly navigate to the files in these directories. I've tried helm-bookmarks but it will only open the bookmarked directory in dired, not offer to open the files in the directory from the helm buffer. Is there a helm source that would do the trick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to do it the other way around: 
+ call helm-bookmarks
+ call helm-find-files from one of the bookmarked directories